# Django access intermediate fields in template

Tags: django

I have django models like this:

```
class FittingBag(models.Model):
     ...
     fittings = models.ManyToManyField("app.Fitting", through="FittingInBagInstances")


class FittingInBagInstances(models.Model):
     fitting = models.ForeignKey("app.Fitting", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     bag = models.ForeignKey("app.FittingBags", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     qty = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Quantity' );
```

Is there any way to access intermediate fields (like "qty" ) from Django template without preparing the date in the view?

Comment: What do you mean with  intermediate fields?

Comment: i try to use through="FittingInBagInstances" in ManyToMany field. it allows to create extra fields in table - this one i called "intermediate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the releverse relation that is constructed by the many-to-many intermediate model:

```
{% for fittingbag in fittingbags %}
    Rendering the fittingbag: {{ fittingbag }}
    {% for fittinginbag in fittingbag.fittinginbaginstances_set.all %}
        qty: {{ fittinginbag.qty }}
        fitting: {{ fittinginbag.fitting }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```